# How to NOT display newline character in Emacs Blank Mode

Tags: emacs, newline, customization

I have set up the Blank Mode in Emacs to display tabs, spaces and hard spaces only. However, I cannot get rid of the newline character. See the following screenshot, they are shown as the grey colored cursors:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You might consider swapping out BlankMode for [WhiteSpace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace), which has replaced it.

Comment: Those voting to migrate to superuser - [programming tools are on topic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your emacs config (which you have not shown us!) to remove the `newline` element from the `blank-chars` BlankMode option.

According to the [BlankMode documentation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BlankMode), the blank-chars option determines which blank characters are visualized by BlankMode.

From the long documentation in the [blank-mode.el package](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/blank-mode.el):

```
(defcustom blank-chars
  '(tabs spaces trailing lines space-before-tab newline
     indentation empty space-after-tab)
  "*Specify which kind of blank is visualized.

It's a list which element value can be:

   trailing     trailing blanks are visualized.

   tabs     TABs are visualized.

   spaces       SPACEs and HARD SPACEs are visualized.

   lines        lines whose have columns beyond
            `blank-line-column' are highlighted.
            Whole line is highlighted.
            It has precedence over
            `lines-tail' (see below).

   lines-tail   lines whose have columns beyond
            `blank-line-column' are highlighted.
            But only the part of line which goes
            beyond `blank-line-column' column.
            It has effect only if `lines' (see above)
            is not present in `blank-chars'.

   space-before-tab SPACEs before TAB are visualized.

   newline      NEWLINEs are visualized.

   indentation  8 or more SPACEs at beginning of line are
            visualized.

   empty        empty lines at beginning and/or end of buffer
            are visualized.

   space-after-tab  8 or more SPACEs after a TAB are visualized.

Any other value is ignored.
```

Comment: That's the thing, in my .emacs file, I only have the following, which implies that only tabs, spaces before tabs and spaces should be visible, yet I see newlines: (blank-chars (quote (tabs space-before-tab spaces)))

Comment: how to you disable this, i cant find blank- anywhere in any file